# dependence of multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, multivariable-calculus

*(I met this question in proving all the integrating factors $\mu_1$ of $P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$ has the form $\mu_1(x,y)=\mu(x,y) g(\Phi)$,where $\mu Pdx+\mu Qdy=d\Phi,\mu$ is also an integrating factor).*

**Question:**

$\Psi(x,y),\Phi(x,y)\in C^k(\mathbb{R^2})(k\geqslant2)$,

$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}$, or equivalently,$
\left |\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}  \\
\end{array}\right|=0.
$

**show that there exisits a differentiable function $g$,$\Psi(x,y)=g(\Phi(x,y))$.**

I think maybe the implicit function theorem could help?Any answer or comment would be appreciated!

Comment: There are many terminology that you're using without the definition in your post, inclusive hypothesis over the functions.

Comment: @EventHorizon sorry for that.I've just edited it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2331270